# Possible bug: Getting -1 reputation for downvoting someone else's post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, review, down-votes

When I am performing review tasks (either Late Answers or First Posts) and I downvote a post, MY reputation is occasionally decremented. I'm not sure whether an additional user is performing a review task on my review and is downvoting me due to possible unfair criticism on my part, but it seems that Stack is accidentally decrementing my reputation instead of the reputation of the user who posted what I reviewed. Examples of this phenomenon can be seen in my reputation description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2105497/sir-digby-chicken-caesar?tab=reputation). (Look under posts "keyword not supported data source" and "iframe z-index dropdown menu".

If what I think is happening is not actually happening please tell me what is actually going on so I can remedy the way I tackle review tasks.

Comment: It's not an accident. It happens when you downvote answers. It's not much so don't stop if it's justified...

Comment: downvoting an answer costs you 1 rep (perhaps to minimize strategic downvoting, perhaps to make sure you really mean it.) downvoting questions is free.

Comment: (Great name by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

That's by design, to discourage you from frivolous downvotes. The person receiving the downvote does lose rep (2) too.

It doesn't penalise you for downvoting questions, just answers, because StackExchange want you to be free to downvote bad questions as much as you like.

Comment: Why not just subject downvotes to a review process like everything else instead of enacting a penalty for downvoting answers? I try not to be critical whenever possible, but when a user is just using an answer to propose their own question or delude the answer pool with a barely thought out answer, it seems more than appropriate.

Comment: If they're using an answer to propose their own question, you should flag it as "not an answer".

Comment: Downvoting _is_ a review process! It shouldn't worry you too much - one upvote to your own post gives you enough rep for ten downvotes on other people's - that should be enough to keep you going.